# C# WPF window resize is blocking NAudio WaveIn / WaveOut stream

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I´m using NAudio and WPF to develop a mixer software in C#.

But I have faced with a non commum behaivour: the output is playing normally, but when I resize the MainWindow, output audio starts spliting. If keep window resize, buffer got full and a exception is throw. It´s looks like resize event is blocking the main thread.

Has someone any suggestion?

```
_wavein = new WaveIn();
_wavein.DeviceNumber = 0;
_wavein.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(0).Channels);
    
waveInProvider = new WaveInProvider(_wavein);
    
volumeSampleProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(waveInProvider.ToSampleProvider());
volumeSampleProvider.Volume = (float)slider.Value;
    
MeteringSampleProvider meteringSampleProvider = new MeteringSampleProvider(volumeSampleProvider, 1000);
meteringSampleProvider.StreamVolume += meteringSampleProviderStreamVolume;
    
_waveOut = new WaveOut();
_waveOut.DesiredLatency = 50;
_waveOut.Init(meteringSampleProvider.ToWaveProvider());

_wavein.StartRecording();
_waveOut.Play();
```

Comment: I'd suggest moving processing to a background thread. This is happening probably because the audo is being processed on the UI thread which is then busy rendering the window so doesn't have time to clear the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `WaveOutEvent` and `WaveOutEvent` the audio processing will happen on a background thread which should help considerably